# If $A\cong B$, $C\cong D$ with $D\trianglelefteq B$, $C \trianglelefteq A$ then $A/C\cong B/D$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $A,B,C,D$ are groups such that $A\cong B$, $C\cong D$ with $D\trianglelefteq B$, $C \trianglelefteq A$. Prove that $A/C\cong B/D$.

**Proof:** Suppose that $f:A\to B$ and $g:C\to D$ are isomorphisms. Define the mapping $T:A/C\to B/D$ by $T(aC)=f(a)D$.

I have shown that mapping $T$ is well-defined, surjective, homomorphism. But I have difficulty to show that it is injective:

Suppose $T(a_1C)=T(a_2C)$ then $f(a_1)D=f(a_2)D$ then $f(a_2^{-1}a_1)\in D$. And I stuck here. Would be very grateful for help!

**EDIT:** Why I created this topic? I was working on third isomorphism theorem which states the following: Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism of $G$ onto $\overline{G}$ with kernel $K$, and let $\overline{N}$ be a normal subgroup of $\overline{G}$. Then $N:=\phi^{-1}(\overline{N})$ is normal in $G$ and $G/N\cong \overline{G}/\overline{N}$. Equivalently, $G/N\cong (G/K)/(N/K)$.

I have understood everything except the last sentence. By 1st isomotphism theorem we know that $G/K\cong \overline{G}$ and $N/K\cong \overline{N}$ then how to derive that $\overline{G}/ \overline{N}\cong (G/K)/(N/K)$??

That's why I asked this question.

Comment: Can't you have $A=B=\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_4$ and two subgroups $C, D$ both isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$, one with quotient isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4$, the other with quotient isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$

Comment: @GEdgar, why don't you type this up as an answer? I was about to, but you beat me to it.

Comment: Yeah, this is false.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you have $A=B=\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_4$ and two subgroups $C, D$ both isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$, such that $A/C \cong \mathbb Z_4$ and   $A/D \cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$

Comment: What do you mean by "one quotient isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$"?

Comment: Re-written.  Is it clear now what it means?

Comment: Please take a look at the EDIT

Comment: So ... the result in the title is false, and thus cannot be used to prove the result in the EDIT.